# Display items in descending order of downloads

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

First of all, I'm using FirebaseUI for android and Firebase Database.

Since firebase querying only supports ordering of data in ascending order so I came up with a little hack to display items in `RecyclerView` in descending order.

Here is how I'm querying.

```
selectedCategory = "downloads"
array = new FirebaseArray(imageRef.orderByChild(selectedCategory).limitToLast(50), ImageModel.class);
```

Here's my implementation on `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Please, note that here I override the method `onBindViewHolder`. This is the method which works to reorder items. But practically it doesn't work as expected (no effect with or without this code. List is same in both cases).

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageModel, GridViewHolder>(
            array,
            R.layout.grid_item,
            GridViewHolder.class) {

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(GridViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, getItemCount() -position - 1);
            populateViewHolder(viewHolder, getItem(position), getItemCount() - position - 1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final GridViewHolder viewHolder, final ImageModel model, final int position) {
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: probably reverse the array ?

Comment: Not possible the array starts getting filled only when adapter is executed.

Comment: I suggest using your own listener and adapter if you want to achieve this.

Comment: @makrandpawar looks like I need to do this only as you suggested. You can write it as an answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort based on the "downloads" count. Why don't you store the value

```
download * (-1)
```

or

```
0 - download
```

This way you will get the desired order in the database and then no more need to work on the Android side.

Comment: Great suggestion but how can change those values now which are already present in the database?

Comment: Maybe you could write a Cloud function or use the Firebase Admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)