# How to sort Firebase records by two fields (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and pass `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` with some query into constructor. Each item has number of fields including timestamp `a` and another integer field `b`. So I want items with older `a` but less `b` to be on top of list. It's easy to implement with sqlite, but not so easy with nosql. It seems I need to add some extra field which keeps both fields:
`String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b)` but how to achieve asc / desc properties?

Loading the whole list and sorting in Java is not an option.

Comment: You seem to already have found how to [filter on multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924) in the Realtime Database. There is no option to have the database reverse the results, but you can: 1) reverse them client-side, which is *always* an option given that you're already loading all the data over a network connection, 2) store an inverted value in a property in the database and order on that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46255310) and more from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+descending).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase Realtime database does not support queries on multiple properties, supports only queries on a single child property. So, you're correct in guessing that you'll need to create an extra field to keep both fields. So to achieve this, you need to create a new field which in your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- itemId
          |
          --- a: valueOfA
          |
          --- b: valueOfB
          |
          --- a_b: valueOfA_valueOfB
```

So as you see, the `a_b` property combines the values that you want to filter on.

Unlike Firebase Realtime database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). You should take a look at this. So a query as the one below is allowed in Cloud Firestore without creating a combined property.

```
itemIdRef.whereEqualTo("a", "valueOfA").whereEqualTo("b", "valueOfB");
```

When you order strings this is the normal ordering method. A quick fix would be to add two zeros before each second element like this: `"1516428687_001"`, `"1516428687_002"`, `"1516428687_012"`. Now your order will be fine. For more explanations, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key).

Comment: the problem is I actually request all items without equalsTo but with order. In this case if I just concatenate two fields then I won't be able to use ASC/DESC as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Speaking about Firebase Realtime database, yes you can, passing the new `a_b` property to order method like this: `.orderBy("a_b")`.

Comment: I thought about it - but in practice it won't work because as I guess internally firebase uses standard strings comparator so the order of three keys will be following  `"1516428687_1", "1516428687_12", "1516428687_2"`. But I need `"1516428687_1", "1516428687_2", "1516428687_12"`. Do you have more ideas @alex-mamo?

Comment: When your order strings this is the normal ordering method. A quick fix would be to add two zeros before each second element like this: `"1516428687_001"`, ` "1516428687_002"`, `"1516428687_012"`. Now your order will be fine. For more explanations, please see my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key). Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, that works, I implemented this approach, but this workaround is far from straightforward solution. For now it seems firebase has huge lack of API. Can you edit your answer, or just add a reference to that another answer, and I accept it?

Comment: You're right but this how things works when it comes to Firebase Realtime database. Give it a try, use Cloud Firestore for your project, it allows compound queries. And yes, just edited my answer. Thanks!