# Firebase query not working (onDataEvent not firing)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have some data in my Firebase. It's structure is
[image]

(assume that there is more data)
I want to get the records where banknoteType ="100_dollar" and userId="1057..."

```
   DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userBanknoteAmount");
    Query firebaseQuery = database.orderByChild(1057...).equalTo(1057...);
            firebaseQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     //todo
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("onCancelledError", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
```

But the `onDataChange`event doesn't fire... What am I mistaking?
EDIT: I am trying to debug it and neither onDataChange nor onCancelled breakpoints stop there

EDIT 2 : The current code I am using is

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference userBanknoteAmountRef = rootRef.child("userBanknoteAmount");
    Query firebaseQuery = userBanknoteAmountRef.orderByChild("userId");//.equalTo(userId);
    firebaseQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("test", "onDataChange: "+postSnapshot);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.wtf("onCancelledError", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

EDIT 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkcx.png

Comment: What does `databaseError.toException()` return?

Comment: @AlexMamo that's the problem it doesn't return any exception

Comment: Did you use `1057...` or the actual number that is in your database? Also i think you should use `.orderByChild("userid")` instead of `orderByChild(1057...)`

Comment: @AndréKool i used the actual number in both places `database.orderByChild(1057...).equalTo(1057...);`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime database does not allow you to chain multiple filter methods. If you want to get the records where : `userId="1057..."`, please change the following line of code:

```
Query firebaseQuery = database.orderByChild(1057...).equalTo(1057...);
```

with

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userBanknoteAmountRef = rootRef.child("userBanknoteAmount");
Query firebaseQuery = userBanknoteAmountRef.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(1057...);
```

If you want to get all the records where `banknoteType ="100_dollar"` and `userId="1057..."`, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)**.

According to your edited post, please also change this line of code:

```
Log.d("test", "onDataChange: "+postSnapshot);
```

to

```
Log.d("test", "onDataChange: "+postSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class));
```

Comment: still doesn't work.. i am trying to debug it ... may it have something with async events?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why isn't working? Do you have an error? Please also see my updated answer.

Comment: actually there can be only 1 record with the same userId and banknoteType... anyway I am not getting any error... I don't know why this isn't working

Comment: Please add the code that you have changed, to see more clearly where the problem might be.

Comment: It means that you have provided a wrong database structure. Please add the real database structure, in which are included 2 children and the root reference.

Comment: In this case should work for sure. I have tested myself. To be sure, can you provide me another another screenshot to be sure?

Comment: @AlexMamo check the question

Comment: It is the same picture. Maybe we can try a TeamViewer. Should work. I have tested.

Comment: @AlexMamo ok let's try teamviewer can we move to a chat session?

Comment: Ok. Give me your access.

Comment: @AlexMamo since if i post the id and password here who knows how many people will join TV haha