# How to get the name of the parent node from the values of child nodes?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the preview of the tree:

[image]

I tried to do this:

```
mRef.orderByChild("desc").equalTo(des).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
    {
        mRef.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(uid).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
            {
                myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            }
    });
});
```

But it returns the value of the previously visited node.

Note: The Parent node "ASSIST Blog" contains many children which may have similar values.

Comment: mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                    mRef=mDatabase.getReference().child("AssistBlog");

Comment: explain an example:what should the input be and the output?

Comment: consider the first node in AssistBlog i.e "-LEmmhJ8zYxWeGrtGWYy"
it has desc as "Press the add icon on top to start adding posts to feed."
and userid as "bd9arFKXCGRwDIqH7dkLjlW8CPk2"
I want to get the parent node "-LEmmhJ8zYxWeGrtGWYy" using user id and desc

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `getKey()` method in your retrieved `dataSnapshot`:

```
final Query userQuery = mRef.orderByChild("First Name");

  userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        map.clear();
        //Get the node from the datasnapshot
        String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
           String key = child.getKey().toString();
           String value = child.getValue().toString();
           map.put(key,value);
        }
```

Comment: This answer was answered on Jan 23 '17 at 14:24
by 
Francisco Durdin Garcia and I tried it.

Comment: problem is the node maynot have unique values, which means more than one node can have values "Firstname"

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Then its work for you. String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey(); this should give your parent key.

Comment: it returns "AssistBlog"

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Then the issue in your query. May be your query not found any record.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with Firebase Realtime database without some changes to your database. Firebase Realtime database does not have the capability to perform filtering on multiple conditions. In SQL terms, cannot use "multiple where clauses". If you want to check for matches on multiple properties, you'll have to create a composite field that contains a combination of the things you're looking for. For example, you'll need a string value that is composed from your `desc` property concatenated with your `userid` property and for this please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)**.

If you are interested, Firestore allows you to filter on multiple conditions and for that I recommend you see the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).