# How to Display Data from Firebase Database to Chat Activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I can get text data based on Firebase database structure like in the picture?

I already create some function to get a text data with "fromID" as a parameter. Now, how I can get the text data based on "fromID" and "toID" as a parameter? Thank you.

[image: Overview of Firebase Database Structure]
[image: This is my code]

Comment: Please show what Android code you've written thus far. For example, we're don't know what your chat activity even looks like. See about having a [mcve]

Comment: @AlexMamo I was wondering why you chose that duplicate instead of the one I proposed?

Comment: @AndréKool Because that duplicate is in Javascript and the OP is asking for a solution in Android. As you can see the tag and the code from it's picture.

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually the question I proposed doesn't have a language tag, it only uses javascript in the answers. It also has more (extencive) answers and it's being used as the go-to dupe target for these kind of questions. Is it maybe a good idea to add it to the duplicate list on this question?

Comment: @AndréKool That's a good idea, just added it.

Comment: OMG the abuse of power

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sample below. first, make a model and set the data using an adapter.

```
 mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);
     String text= dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Firebase Realtime database without some significant changes in your database structure. Realtime Database doesn't have the capability to perform filtering on multiple conditions (in SQL terms, "multiple where clauses"). If you want to check for matches on multiple properties like `fromID1` and `toID`, you'll have to create a composite field that contains a combination of those two properties. For instance, you'll need a String value that has `fromID1` and `toID` concatenated together like this:

```
fromID1_toID
```

You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)**.

Note, if you'll later decide to to change your database to Firestore, please note that this feature is available, you can filter on multiple conditions.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Does OP actually get pinged when you leave a message under your answer instead of the question?

Comment: @AndréKool As far as I know, it is.

Comment: You made me doubt so I did some digging. And according to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications) OP doesn't get notified for a comment on an answer.

Comment: @AndréKool Hmmm. Didn't know that. Thanks a lot!