# SQL Query to Firebase query

Tags: android, sql, firebase

The SQL query that I want to apply is:

```
SELECT time FROM Appointment WHERE date = "3/15/2019" AND time = "9:00AM"
```

but I don't know how to translate it in Firebase. I am using Firebase in Android Studio. My goal here is to prevent date and time duplicate since the app that I'm developing is an online appointment.

Database:

```
Appointment
    angelcrist
        aptype: "Objective(Computerized)"
        date: "3/15/2019"
        name: "Hephep Horray"
        time: "9:00AM"
    miriammejia
        aptype: "Objective(Computerized)"
        date: "3/5/2019"
        name: "Romz Ysmael"
        time: "9:00AM"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can do this with the Firebase realtime database. It does **not** have the capability to perform filtering on multiple conditions. If you have a SQL background, I can say that there are no "multiple where clauses" in Firebase. If you want to check for matches on multiple properties, you'll have to create a composite field as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to sort Firebase records by two fields (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)

If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), please note it allows you to filter on multiple conditions. Chaning multiple whereTo calls are working perfectly fine.

Comment: oh..That's what I'm thinking too; the query limitations of firebase. But anyway, thanks. I will try the Cloud Firestore..

Comment: You're welcome! I also recommend you to try Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch your Appointment data for that particular date using below query, and loop through dataSnapshot childrens to check if you have the time available for that date.

```
reference.orderByChild('date').equalTo("<yourDate>")
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               //Check for time here
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
});
```

Comment: I did that already. The problem is, it gets all the values of time. But I'll still try it again. Thanks!