# Fetching specific data from firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Trying to fetch related data from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSkdA.png)

I am new in Android and I am stuck here, want to retrieve data from Firebase where "del_id = 1" and "date = 2019-3-18" but I don't know how to write as Firebase way to retrieve what I want, Image above will further demonstrate what I have tried and what I want.

Your answer will be highly valuable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
invSnapsjot.getValue(Invoice.class)
```

Returns an object of type `Invoice` and **not** a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) object so you can call `.child()` method on it.

If you want to get a specific element `(del_id = 1)`, you should simply use a query that looks like this:

```
myDatabase.orderByChild("del_id").equalTo("1").addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

Unfortunately, Firebase realtime database does not support queries on multiple properties but there is still a workaround for that, so please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to sort Firebase records by two fields (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **write or update** value at that time you need to take .addValueEventListener

If you want to only **set your value** in firebase you directly set value without using .addValueEventListener

More details refer this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write