# firebase: add condition 'where' property between 2 values

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My structure database (database product):

```
{
...
data: {
    value_a: 15.2,
    value_b: 7.1
  }
},
{
...
data: {
    value_a: 14.1
    value_b: 2.5
  }
},
{
...
data: {
    value_a: 16.7
    value_b: 5.2
  }
}
```

my request
a) I would like to return a list of products if value_a is between 14 and 15
b) I would like to return a list product if value_a is between 14 and 15 and value_b is between 2 and 5.

I check the operator 'in' but isn't work for the (a).

```
 firestore().collection('products')
            .where("data.value_a", "in", [14, 15])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) I would like to return list of products if value_a is between 14 and 15

To solve this, you should use the following query:

```
firestore().collection('products')
        .where("data.value_a", ">=", 14)
        .where("data.value_a", ">=", 15)
```

However,

> b) I would like to return a list product if value_a is between 14 and 15 and value_b is between 2 and 5.

It's not possible. There is no way you can filter records based on multiple properties. There is a workaround, so please check my answer from the following post:

- [How to sort Firebase records by two fields (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator only works if you have a list of values for `value_a`. To achieve what you want you should combine queries:

```js
firestore().collection('product_geoloc')
    .where("data.value_a", ">=", 14)
    .where("data.value_a", "<=", 15)
```

Comment: The second solution is definitely not possible. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android).