# How to search Firebase database by any field?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way I could search by any Reatime Firebase Database field? Right now I know how to search by FP_CarNumber, but I would like to search by others as well like  `SP_CarNumber` or `SP_CarNumber` and `FP_CarNumber` at the same time.

```java
    private void txtSearch(String str){
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainModel>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Declaration_Data").child(currentuser).child("Declarations").orderByChild("FP_CarNumber").startAt(str).endAt(str + "\uf8ff"), MainModel.class)
                        .build();

        mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
        mainAdapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Realtime Database **only** supports queries on single field property. I have explained in one o my answers:

- [How to sort Firebase records by two fields (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340925/how-to-sort-firebase-records-by-two-fields-android)

How to solve such a situation by creating an extra field to keep the other values. Unfortunately, that workaround doesn't apply to all situations.

Besides that, as far as I know, there is no library that does that automatically in Android. However, there is one for the web, written by David East called [Querybase](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase).

So unlike in the Realtime Database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). So I recommend you try that.